# How to combine data from multiple rows when common column headings exist?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a fairly large data-set that needs to be exported as CSV from Excel for import into another application. It can not have duplicate column headings but at this time there are many instances of that happening. I need to consolidate these headings and their respective data into single columns and remove duplicates.

I am trying to take data like this:

```
MAKE | MAKE | MAKE | MODEL | MODEL | TRIM |
-------------------------------------------
FORD |      |      |       |       |      |
-------------------------------------------    
     | FIAT |      |       |       |      |
-------------------------------------------
     |      | MINI |       |       |      |
-------------------------------------------
     |      |      | PILOT |       |      |
-------------------------------------------
     |      |      |       | SC400 |      |
-------------------------------------------
     |      |      |       |       | EX   |
-------------------------------------------
```

and turn it into this:

```
MAKE | MODEL | TRIM |
---------------------
FORD |       |      |
---------------------    
FIAT |       |      |
---------------------
MINI |       |      |
---------------------
     | PILOT |      |
---------------------
     | SC400 |      |
---------------------
     |       | EX   |
---------------------
```

Thanks in advance for any help in accomplishing this.

Comment: y'know, if there was less than 255 rows, I'd transpose the data, then query it (using ADO and Excel ODBC driver), consolidate the records, before transposing it back again :)

Comment: how many rows of data do you have - more or less than 255?

Comment: Over 2000 rows in this spreadsheet.

Comment: are you in Excel 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate the problem in smaller bits:

1. Read the unique titles and save them in a Dictionary object (as a value you might want to hold on the column they are going to be saved in)
2. You iterate through each cell getting the value and reading the column header.
3. You write that value in a new sheet on the column you are currently iterating through but for column position you look-up the current column title in the dictionary and get its position.

EDIT: Code tested and debugged. Works well.

Note: This method assumes that you have only 1 value per duplicated columns per row.
      If you have more than 1 value for duplicated columns then the program will always save the last one (as it will overwrite the previous value). If you want a method that handles multiple values per column then you need to keep a Row number for each column in the new sheet and increment it by 1 each time you write data in that column.

```
Sub WriteValues()

    'Aassuming your column titles are in row 1
    Dim mainSheet As Worksheet
    Set mainSheet = ActiveSheet

    Dim maxCols As Integer
    Dim maxRows As Double
    maxRows = 0
    maxCols = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Dim colPositions As Dictionary
    Set colPositions = New Dictionary

    'Iterate throgh row 1 to get all uniue values
    Dim iCol As Integer
    For iCol = 1 To maxCols
        On Error Resume Next
            colPositions.Add Cells(1, iCol).Value, colPositions.Count + 1
        On Error GoTo 0
        'Also record maxRows
        If Cells(rows.Count, iCol).rows.End(xlUp).row > maxRows Then
            maxRows = Cells(rows.Count, iCol).rows.End(xlUp).row
        End If
    Next i

    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Set newSheet = Sheets.Add

    Dim col As Integer
    Dim row As Double


    'Write column titles in new sheet
    Dim v As Variant
    iCol = 1
    For Each v In colPositions
        Cells(1, iCol).Value = v
        iCol = iCol + 1
    Next v

    'Main data iterator
             For row = 2 To maxRows
      For col = 1 To maxCols

        Dim cellValue As String
        Dim valueColumn As String

         With mainSheet
            cellValue = .Cells(row, col).Value
            valueColumn = .Cells(1, col).Value
         End With
         If cellValue <> "" Then
            newSheet.Cells(row, colPositions(valueColumn)).Value = cellValue
         End If
        Next col
    Next row
End Sub
```

Comment: Potter, I'm not very experienced with VBA developer. Should this work in Excel 2010? I get an error that says "User-defined type not defined" where you have "Dim colPositions As Dictionary"

Comment: Oh.. you need to add a reference to Miscrosoft Scripting Runtime to use the Dictionary object. Go to Tools->References find Miscrosoft Scripting Runtime and click it.

Comment: "VBA Scripting Runtime" is not in the list of "Available References".

Comment: Sorry I edited my comment it should be "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"

PS: Make sure you copy the latest version of the code as I edited it a few times

Comment: That did exactly what I needed it to do. Thank you so much!

Comment: +1 for using Dictionary object :) I might spend some time building a Transpose & SQL ADO solution at home tonight though just to be bloodymided!